# Prove $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2\cos(8A)}}}=2\cos A$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that:

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2\cos(8A)}}}=2\cos A$

Is this trigonometric identity correct?, I tried by using compound formulae for cos8A but couldn’t get it to RHS, give your try and if correction is to be made, suggest suitable correction.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust, now I'm finally sure about adding +2 with cos8A inside inner 3rd  square root.

Comment: Just checking mentally with a simple value for $A$, for example $A=0$, shows this formula to be false in general.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos2a=2\cos^2a-1,$$ so that
$$\pm\sqrt{2+2\cos2a}=2\cos a.$$
Iterate
$$\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2+2\cos4a}}=2\cos a,$$
$$\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2+2\cos8a}}}=2\cos a$$
$$\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2+2\cos16a}}}}=2\cos a$$
$$...$$

Comment: When I put a = 90 degrees in the 1st iteration, LHS is not equal to RHS.

Comment: @Yyes, \sqrt{2+2\cos2a}\ge0, so must be $2\cos a\iff \cos a\ge0$

Comment: @Mick: I have inserted $\pm$ signs everywhere as should. Now check again. I leave it as an exercise to discuss the signs depending on the value of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The identity isn't true in general.

Take $A=3$, for example. $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2\cos(8\cdot3)}}}\approx1.93$ but $2\cos(3)\approx -1.98$.

Though the left hand side looks slightly like [Liu Hui's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_pi#Other_classical_formulae) or [Viète's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula) formula approximation to $\pi$ if you're interested.

Comment: @ Eul Can, i appreciate that approximation.